# Show that $\sum_{n \neq 0} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{in} e^{in\theta} = 2 \sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n+1} \frac{\sin n\theta}{n}$.

Tags: complex-analysis, fourier-analysis

> Show that 
>   $$\sum_{n \neq 0} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{in} e^{in\theta} = 2 \sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n+1} \frac{\sin n\theta}{n}.$$

This is not an exercise. It is an example from Stein, Fourier Analysis - An Introduction, pg. 36. I'm rusty on my complex algebra and I'm having trouble understanding why this equality is true. I used the complex exponential identity $e^{ix} = \cos(x) + i\sin(x)$ without success.

Comment: Did you try to sum the terms $n$ and $-n$, for some fixed $n\geqslant1$, and see what happens?

Comment: Could you post the part of the book's solution that you don't understand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key here is that $e^{in\theta} = \cos(n\theta) + i\sin(n\theta)$ implies that
$$
    e^{in\theta} - e^{-in\theta} = 2i\sin(n\theta).
$$
Thus the sum on the left hand side is, after rearranging terms (grouping those indexed by $\pm n$) and simplifying,
$$
    \sum_{n > 0} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{in}(e^{in\theta}-e^{-in\theta})
    = 2 \sum_{n > 0} (-1)^{n+1} \frac{\sin(n\theta)}{n}.
$$
I'll leave the question to you of why this reordering is acceptable here.

Answer (score 1):

Use $\sin n\theta = \dfrac{e^{in\theta} - e^{-in\theta}}{2i}$ and observe the sum on the left can be written as
$$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \left[ \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{in} e^{in\theta} + \frac{(-1)^{-n+1}}{i(-n)} e^{i(-n)\theta} \right].$$

Answer (score 0):

By direct calculation,
$\sum_{n\neq0}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{n+1}}{in}e^{in\theta} =\sum_{n=-\infty}^{-1}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{n+1}}{in}e^{in\theta}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{n+1}}{in}e^{in\theta}
 =\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{-n+1}}{\left(-1\right)in}e^{-in\theta}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{n+1}}{in}e^{in\theta}
 =\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{n+1}}{in}\left(e^{in\theta}-e^{-in\theta}\right)
 =2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(-1\right)^{n+1}\frac{\sin\left(n\theta\right)}{n}.$